# WPF Command Line Argument Routing

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, parameters, command-line-arguments

I have a WPF application that I'm starting to develop. I have a 40 or so methods that are accessible through the UI, but also need to be executed by passing parameters via the command line.

Currently i have the following, that allows me to catch the arguments on the App.xaml.cs...

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    string[] args = MyApplication.GetCommandLineArgs();

    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int index = 1; index < args.Length; index += 2)
        {
            dictionary.Add(args[index], args[index + 1]);
        }

        if (dictionary.Keys.Contains("/Task"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is a Task");

        }
    }
}
}
```

I am looking to pass a argument at the start of every call through the command line. If i pass

> /Task ThisIsTheTask

I can read this from the dictionary. And then execute the related method.

My question is what is the best way of "routing" the task parameter to a specific method. I will also be passing additional parameters  after the task that will need to be passed to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be considered an implementation of the service-locator anti-pattern, but one simple approach would be to have something like the following:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Action<string[]>> commands = new Dictionary<string, Action[]>
{
    {"Task1", args => Task1Method(args[0], Int32.Parse(args[1]))}
}

private static Task1Method(string firstArgs, int secondArg)
{
}
```

Your code can then locate an `Action<string[]>` for the task specified on the command line, and pass the remaining parameters to the `Action`, e.g.

```
var commandLineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
var taskName = commandLineArgs[1];

// Locate the action to execute for the task
Action<string[]> action;
if(!commands.TryGetValue(taskName, out action))
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Task not found");
}

// Pass only the remaining arguments
var actionArgs = new string[commandLineArgs.Length-2];
commandLineArgs.CopyTo(actionArgs, 2);

// Actually invoke the handler
action(actionArgs);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use third-party, open source libraries I would suggest taking a look at [ManyConsole](https://github.com/fschwiet/ManyConsole/), it is available via NuGet [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ManyConsole/).

ManyConsole allows you to define `ConsoleCommand` implementations (see [here](https://github.com/fschwiet/ManyConsole/blob/master/SampleConsole/EchoStringsCommand.cs) for an example implementation), which can have many parameters. You are then able to use a `ConsoleCommandDispatcher` to route to the appropriate `ConsoleCommand` implementation based upon the command-line arguments (see [here](https://github.com/fschwiet/ManyConsole/blob/master/SampleConsole/Program.cs) for an example).

I am in no way affiliated with ManyConsole, but I have used the library and found it to be very effective.

Comment: Looks good @Lukazoid, unfortunately i cant use any third party library's. Thanks though. Ill bookmark that for the future :-)

Comment: @MrBeanzy Ah that's a shame, hope you can get some inspiration from the project, I will leave this answer here in case anyone else finds the information useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest one (or more) properties on the application class of your program that expose them. Access during runtime can then be done by using something like

```
(Application.Current as App).MyTask
```

which can then be further wrapped for convenience.
Also, you can write your own "Main" method in WPF too - that way you would have easier access to the parameters array and could do processing before WPF starts up if you need to. I'll edit in how if you need that.